# What are viable alternatives to github's lack of a proper folder structure?

Tags: github, structure, directory

We're (our team of developers) considering of picking up a really big project that we thought we'd split up across multiple modules, but we would still like to keep the code centralised somehow.

We thought about having them under a folder structure, that would basically be the separation which we need to achieve the split while still maintaining good proximity and a logical hierarchy too.

Unfortunately GitHub doesn't seem very supportive of a folder structure.

Did I miss something? Does GitHub have the support that I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use git [*submodules*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). You will create a repository for each module, then, under a centralized repository (which will act as the folder) you can have folders that point to other repositories.

The way to adding submodules is:

```
$ git submodule add https://github.com/username/modulename
```

Repeat this for each of the modules.

Then you can work on each repository as usual, and when you want to update the central repository to have the most recent versions you will do:

```
$ git submodule update --remote
```